# bash history is appended, but histappend is off

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.04

I'm on ubuntu 10.4 and my shell is `bash`.
When I open several gnome terminals and close them history is properly appended.
When I enter `shopt` it says among other things:

```
histappend      off
```

Can anyone tell me where the append behaviour is configured?

Comment: retagging 'ubuntu-10.04-lts' since ubuntu-10.10 isn't out yet.  tho i hear it's to be named something Meerkat.

Comment: btw, my bash shells on Lucid all show *histappend* as **on** ... no tweaks yet ... have you tweaked your *bash* configuration already?

Comment: @quack: Thanks, I'm ahead of my time, as always;-)

Comment: @quack: I have upgraded this install several times, so I'm not 100% sure. For me it doesn't matter if histappend is on or off, history is always appended. What I'm really curious about is why this happens? It would be insightful, if you could shopt -u histappend and tell me if it is still appended in your install?

Answer (score 2):

`bash` tries to append history as much as possible. With `histappend` on, you will guarantee always appending history. If it is off, history will still be appended until the number of commands you enter in an interactive `bash` session becomes greater than [`HISTSIZE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTSIZE). When this happens, history will be overwritten.

If you want to explicitly overwrite history, you can use `history -w` in `.bash_logout` or an exit trap.

I posted in more detail in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428208/238373) about how `bash` history append works.

Answer (score 1):

`histappend` is the setting I would expect to control this. Since those aren't login shells, it won't be something going on in `/etc/bash.bash.logout` or `~/.bash_logout`. Check to see if a trap is set by entering `trap -p`. Also do `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` to see if something is going on there.

Comment: echo $PROMPT_COMMAND returns
echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007".

trap -p returns nothing.
I have no /etc/bash.logout and ~/.bash_logout contains nothing regaring history.

Answer (score -1):

I  wrote a [quick tip](https://thismagpie.com/append-bash-history/) about setting histappend this on my site but I will paraphrase the post here, to answer your question, I hope.

You should be able to configure histappend to be 'on' by using shopt.

To enable run

> shopt -s histappend

To disable run

> shopt -u histappend

Does that help?